# VB.NET Using Interface, Reflection, and DLL to Access Main Form Controls Properties

Tags: vb.net, reflection, dll, interface

I have a main form, a separate plugin interface dll and another separate dll. Now this is my problem:
I'd like to access the properties of the controls of the main form for manipulation in the other dll.

Example:
MainForm
Plugins.dll
Data.dll

Main form have label control
I define properties in the interface Plugins.dll
from Data.dll I load Plugins to read the label control from the mainform

The question is how can I do that? Can you please post a sample code here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have control of the main form the interface dll and the plugin the simplest design pattern is to create an interface that the main form implements.

```
Public Interface IMainForm
    Property Mainlabel As System.Windows.Forms.Label
End Interface

Public Class MyForm
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form
    Implements IMainForm

    Public lbl As System.Windows.Forms.Label

    Public Property Mainlabel As System.Windows.Forms.Label Implements IMainForm.Mainlabel
        Get
            Return lbl
        End Get
        Set(value As System.Windows.Forms.Label)
            lbl = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Then Pass in a ref to a Imain form in the extension calling code no reflection required.

Comment: I've implemented this kind of code and it is working to some extent. However, the other class needs to know the specific label control to write data into. So i need to pass the name of the control instead of declaring a new label control type. What i did is something like this: I interface a method and on the main form I added the controls there, and then I called that method in the dll. To my surprise the method runs but the controls inside (label.text="something") did not execute. This does not return any error. What do you think?

Comment: The interface will allow it "know" anything you put in the interface.  Not sure I understand your scenario.

Comment: Yes you are right, the interface runs the method. But i wonder why the code inside that method did not reflect on the main form.

Comment: @brukekek: When you define an interface, and then call the implementor, it runs in the context of the implementor.  I.e. if you have an interface with a method "setLabel1", and your mainform implements this interface, if label1 isn't set, then it's because of a bug in setlabel1 in the mainform.

Comment: Now I understand, you cannot execute/change directly the control's properties right inside the dll. You can just manipulate the value of a certain property and send it back to the main form for processing. And in the main form, any values return from the dll can now be consumed by the controls and execute it like label.visible = (return values from dll). What I did before is I pass the control name in the dll and change its properties there. In summary, all child controls of the main form can only be executed within its scope. You can access its properties but can't execute it inside the dll.

Answer (score 1):

It would be best if you create a separate function that does the task and export the function.